# Is that possible to make timer (clock) quick access from lock screen? A calculator?

Tags: android

I moved from iPhone to Android (Samsung S7) and missing one feature. In iPhone I could use quick access to set clock and timer and set direct from locked screen if to press a button at quick access panel, shown at the picture with arrow. Is it possible to make a similar quick access to clock app in android from lock screen? To put it in android quick access panel or in some other way like third party app, etc: aiming to access clock app set on lock screen quick w/o logging in? Same question with Calculator app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Android you can do almost everything with apps.
I found here some apps that allow you to create widgets on your lockscreen, you click on them, unlock your screen, and the app launches:
https://www.maketecheasier.com/launch-apps-lockscreen-android/

I own a OnePlus so I know they have this option build in.
You can also use the Xposed module "GravityBox" or "LockscreenMods"

(it is not possible to bypass the unlockscreen through a lockscreen widget!)

Comment: Ok, I see. Thanks. Will look up for apps.